# implementing operator== when using inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a base class which implements the == operator.
I want to write another class, inheriting the base class, and which should reimplement the == operator.

Here is some sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
  Person(std::string Name) { m_Name = Name; };

  bool operator==(const Person& rPerson)
  {
    return m_Name == rPerson.m_Name;
  }

private:
  std::string m_Name;
};

class Employee : public Person
{
public:
  Employee(std::string Name, int Id) : Person(Name) { m_Id = Id; };

  bool operator==(const Employee& rEmployee)
  {

    return (Person::operator==(rEmployee)) && (m_Id == rEmployee.m_Id);
  }

private:
  int m_Id;
};

void main()
{
  Employee* pEmployee1 = new Employee("Foo" , 1);
  Employee* pEmployee2 = new Employee("Foo" , 2);

  if (*pEmployee1 == *pEmployee2)
  {
    std::cout << "same employee\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "different employee\n";
  }

  Person* pPerson1 = pEmployee1;
  Person* pPerson2 = pEmployee2;

  if (*pPerson1 == *pPerson2)
  {
    std::cout << "same person\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "different person\n";
  }
}
```

This sample code give the following result :

```
different employee
same person
```

Where I would like, even when handling Person* pointers, to make sure they are different.

How am I supposed to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: i believe you are trying to solve the wrong problem. if you need an == operator that works based on the reference/pointer type you shouldn't have used inheritance in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to do is essentiall "virtualize" the comparison operator.

<del>Since operators cannot be virtual</del> (operators can be `virtual`), you will need to delegate it to something else.  Here's one possible solution.

```
class Person
{
   public:
      /* ... */
      bool operator==(const Person& rhs)
      {
         return m_Name == rPerson.m_Name && this->doCompare(rhs);
      }
   private:
      virtual bool doCompare() = 0;
   };
}
class Employee : public Person
{
   /* ... */
   private:
      virtual bool doCompare(const Person& rhs)
      {
         bool bRetval = false;
         const Employee* pRHSEmployee = dynamic_cast<const Employee*>(&rhs);
         if (pEmployee)
         {
            bRetval = m_Id == pRHSEmployee->m_Id
         }
         return bRetval;
      }
};
```

The question didn't make clear whether Person needs to be a concrete class.  If so, you can make it not pure-virtual, and implement it to return true.

This also uses RTTI, which you may or may not be happy with.

Comment: c++ allows operators to be virtual. but i wouldn't make them virtual. polymorphism and operators actually don't fit together very well (and free operator functions obviously can't be virtual at all).

Comment: If you are going to do this, then you should call both `this->doCompare(that)` and `that.doCompare(*this)` to ensure symmetry

Answer (score 7):

Add a virtual function int Compare(const Person& rPerson) and use that in your operators

Answer (score 6):

You still have a major problem if you have one person and one employee - the person may compare equal to the employee, but not the employee to the person. i.e:

```
(employee == person) != (person == employee)
```

This is a bad thing (tm). Basically you've made an equality operator that isn't [symmetric](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EqualityOperator)

Edit:

Ok, no virtual operators - add the virtual Compare function suggested elsewhere I think - but you still have the symmetric problem.

Comment: `employee == person` doesn't even compile for the OP's code.

Answer (score 5):

There is no neat solution to this problem.

Which is not a problem actually, in C++. What sense does it makes to compare entities on a equality basis?

EDIT: a few links to meditate regarding the pertinence of equality applied to entities:

- [Objects Of Value](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/ObjectsOfValue.pdf), Kevlin Henney
- [Secrets Of Equals](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html), by Angelika Langer, check "Entities vs values" section

EDIT2 (2018 nov 27th):

There is another problem here, problem which also has its root in OO design, not in C++. It's impossible to design a comparison operator that is reflexive (`x == x`), symmetric (`x == y <=> y == x`), and transitive (`x == y && y == z => x == z`) , that also complies with [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). There is a thorough demonstration of this limitation in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*, 2nd ed.

TL;DR: Let's say we have `ColouredPoint` that inherits from `Point`, a function that works on references to `Point`s and that needs to compare them. If *{1,2} == {1,2,blue}* , we will end up with *{1,2,blue} == {1,2,green}*. Or we refuse to compare points with coloured points, which breaks LSP. And so on. There is no solution. My conclusion is that inheriting comparison, while it's a appealing, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't get your point. Can you explain in more detail, why such a comparison doesn't make sense?

Comment: My point is that equality make no sense on entities, and that the OP is wasting his times solving something that is not to be solved, nor can be solved (see Java debates on isEquals implementation)

Comment: ...Take twins, they are very similar, in some sense we may see them as equals. But who cares ? People are either identical, or not...

Comment: I totally agree, but maybe you should develop your answer a little, to explain what are entity and value semantics, and evoke the similarity with Java equals.

Comment: never thought of this deeply. looks like i have to read about something the next hours. lol :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't found THE link that explains everything in simple words. I know it, I feel it, but I can't make a short answer on the subject.

Comment: Luc, this is extremely interesting. Thank you for the links!

Comment: isn't there a simple definition. "equal objects deep compare to equal iif all members compare to equal" there is a proposal in C++20 I believe to make this operator implicitly generated. we already had deep copy construction for free (of code), now we will have free compare. Compare that to C# when you want to deep copy you need to invoke a serializer which will use runtime info to reflect on the type fields, and no help for deep equal. Though I will read the links for science.

Comment: @v.oddou. Comparing fields is not enough. See my _EDIT2_  about the (design) impossibility to have a reflexive, symmetric and transitive comparison function that complies with LSP.

Comment: It's only a problem that manifests with inheritance. In my personal case, I rarely use that practice. Not only composition is 90% of times the better answer. But oftentimes a more procedural paradigm is neater too by my tastes.

Comment: @v.oddou. OK. As this question is about comparing when inheritance is used, I assumed you also implied that context. It doesn't change much the situation. We already have many entities in the standard for instance (streams, mutex...) it doesn't make any sense to copy them, and it also doesn't make any sense to compare them. Automatically generated comparison could be interesting, but as with copy, sometime the best thing to do is to `= delete` these operations.

Answer (score 2):

The big question here is - how do you determine equality?

Can any object be compared to any other object in the hierarchy?  Can only objects of the same type be compared? Where does the criteria for the comparison live?

The solution implementation will depend on the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have the same person equal two different employees but that is what you class design allows. You are better off arranging for identity to be attached to a person. You then ask if a.identity() == b.identity().

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `operator==` symmetric you have to have a person and employee with the same shared details differ so that:

```
Person p("Foo");
Employee e("Foo" , 1);
p == e; // false
e == p; // false
```

This is unintuitive but necessary.

To do this you can use the [`typeid` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)

```
bool operator==(const Person& other) const
{
     return m_Name == other.m_Name && typeid(other) == typeid(*this);
}
```

Of course `Person` must be a polymorphic type (have at least one virtual function).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Person::operator== virtual.

Comment: -1. Making Person::operator== virtual is not sufficient: Employee::operator== must be rewritten to have the same signature. Moreover, this would still lead to the issue pointed by Douglas, i.e. assymetry of the comparison operation, which is...weird.

Comment: I don't think you can make operators virtual.

Comment: @JohnMcG  Why can't I make operators virtual? See [Can I make operator== virtual to implement equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586685/can-i-make-operator-virtual-to-implement-equality)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take  operator== outside of the class scope. In which case, you can either create necessary overloads or make it generic by way of templates.