# Inheriting and overriding virtual assignment == operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565765/implementing-operator-when-using-inheritance), but that discussion is only about comparing operator that takes base or derived class as parameter. In my case I would like to inherit virtual operator for totally different parameter (std::string in this case) and I couldn't find even a discussion on this topic.

So in my case I have following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::string s) : str(s) {}
    virtual bool operator==(const std::string& s) const { return s == str; };


protected:
    std::string str;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(std::string s) : Base(s) {}
    //bool operator==(const std::string& s) const override { return s == str; };
    //bool operator==(const double& d) const { return d == doub; };
protected:
    double doub;
};


int main() {
    std::string foo = "foo";
    Derived object(foo);

    if (object == foo)
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
}
```

operator for string is correctly derived (code is compiling) in this case. But if I would like to define another operator, for type double (uncommenting second comment), code is not compiling, as compiler does not see operator for string defined in base class. Uncommenting first comment, i.e. explicitly overriding base's operator works again.

Can anyone explain such behaviour?

Comment: comparison? Usually, you don't compare the objects, but you have a pointer and you can then just call `obj->compare(str)`.

Comment: A virtual assignment operator is a design error 146 times out of 100. == is not an assignment though. A virtual == operator is a design error only about 95 times out of 100.

Comment: When you have a derived class that has a member function with a different signature then the one in the base class, it *hides* the one in the base class.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for pointing out the errors. I could learn something and agree if you could explain your thesis or point me to sources.

Comment: @Eljay - thanks, that clears everything

Comment: I didn't actually point out specific errors yet. Asymmetry of your == is a big one. Why is myBase == myString good, but myString == myBase bad? Is this expected? What about myBase == myDerived and myDerived == myBase?

Comment: @n.m. I know it works this way and no, it is not expected, but I didn't went so far yet. But, ok. Let's say I'll switch to methods, instead of operators - is it possible to achieve what I wanted? Inherit one method implementation for std::string from base class and implement second one for double with the same name? Or maybe this is design issue as well?

Comment: Yes sure, you need to use `using` to bring the parent method in scope, just like the answer says.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(std::string s) : Base(s) {}
    bool operator==(const double& d) const { return d == doub; };
protected:
    double doub;
};
```

The problem here is that your `Derived::operator==` function *hides* the `Base::operator==` function.

This can be solved by pulling the `operator==` symbol from the `Base` class into the `Derived` class, with the `using` keyword:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(std::string s) : Base(s) {}
    using Base::operator==;   // Get the symbol from the Base class into the scope of the Derived class
    bool operator==(const double& d) const { return d == doub; };
protected:
    double doub;
};
```

Comment: Alright, make sense, but why this same behaviour does not affect methods overriding?

Comment: @MaksPiechota Overriding also hides the base-class function, but it also *implements* the overridden function so the parent-class function won't be called anyway.