# How to do unordered containers of inherited objects in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

The problem in question is related to the question and discussion found in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565765/implementing-operator-when-using-inheritance).

The problem is essentially as follows, I have an abstract class called `players`. Then I have two classes `attackers` and `defenders`. Now, I would like to have an unordered container (`map`, `set`, etc.) containing all players. For that I need a hash function (which is not the issue as both attackers and defenders have names) and an equality function. The latter is the problem. As discussed in the linked SO thread, it seems to be bad practice to inherit `operator==` and I can see why.

I now wonder what the idiomatic solution to my problem is. Is it to just have two containers? One for players and one for attackers? Are there other solutions?

Edit:
Yes, I am talking about `unordered_*` containers. I am aware that I would need to store pointers in the containers rather than objects themselves. For example, I'd have a container `std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<players>> all_players`.

Comment: You have more fundamental problems to deal with. Setting aside the issue of `==`, you cannot have a container of abstract objects, like instances of your `players`. C++ does not work this way. Do a stackoverflow search for "object slicing".

Comment: It entirely depends what you need; you could go with `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<player>, PlayerPtrHash, PlayerPtrEquals>`. You could store the objects in seperate vectors and simply store info about the type and index info in the map/set. Btw: you do realize that `std::map`/`std::set` are order-based; `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` are collection types that don't have a specific order of elements. I recommend going with the approach that gets your program working as quickly as possible, but design it in a way that would later allow you to swap the logic easily.

Comment: Of course I am talking about what C++ supports. In this case this would be a `unordered_whatever<players_pointertype>`, not `unordered_whatever<players>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your map, you can specify a comparator:

```
template< class InputIt >
map( InputIt first, InputIt last,
    const Compare& comp = Compare(), /// << this here
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Then, you don't need to define the equality operator. **In any case, in order to store polymorphic objects in a `map`, you'll need to store pointers**.

So, you would need a comparator anyway, in order to compare the objects, not the pointer values.

Comment: OP is asking for `unordered_map` (though answer is almost same)

Answer (score 0):

In order to store multiple different types in the same container, you have to take advantage of polymorphism.
Polymorphism requires you to use pointers to objects instead of actual objects. That's because C/C++ doesn't allow you to make arrays of multiple different types. The best way to do that in modern C++ is to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` from `#include <memory>`

To make a polymorphic container you'll need the following:

- A common base `struct`/`class` that all of your types inherit from.
- Some way to interface with subtype-specific methods/members.
  This can be a `virtual` method in the base object, a member of the base object, or you can also use `typeid` to figure out what type something is at runtime.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

struct base {
  virtual ~base() = default;
  virtual int GetValue() const = 0;
};

struct A : base {
  int a;
  A(const int v) : a{ v } {}
  int GetValue() const override { return a; }

  void doSomething() const { std::cout << "Hello World!"; }
};
struct B : base {
  int b;
  int mult;
  
  B(const int v, const int mult) : b{ v }, mult{ mult } {}
  int GetValue() const override { return b * mult; }

  void doSomethingElse() const { std::cout << "!dlroW olleH"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>(5));    //< insert an object of type A
  vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>(8, 2)); //< insert an object of type B

  for (const auto& it : vec) {
    std::cout << it->GetValue() << '\t';
    
    if (typeid(*it.get()) == typeid(A)) {
      ((A*)it.get())->doSomething(); 
    }
    else if (typeid(*it.get()) == typeid(B)) {
      ((B*)it.get())->doSomethingElse();
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
5   Hello World!
16  !dlroW olleH
```

Comment: you arent actually answering OPs question. `std::vector` doesnt require `==` nor any comparison

Answer (score 0):

You need a hash function-object that looks through your pointers. The base class can have non-virtual implementations, or equivalently you can have the hasher inspect the public members.

```
class players {
public:
    size_t hash() const;
    friend bool operator==(const player & lhs, const player & rhs);
};

using std::unique_ptr<players> players_ptr;

struct players_hash {
    size_t operator()(const players_ptr & ptr) { return ptr->hash(); }
};

struct players_equal {
    bool operator()(const players_ptr & lhs, const players_ptr & rhs) { return *lhs == *rhs; }
};

std::unordered_set<players_ptr, players_hash, players_equal> all_players;
```

Comment: In the `players_equal` struct when you call `*lhs ==*rhs` what operator is `==` referring to? Is it the equality operator defined in the derived classes of `player`?

Comment: @julian no, the free function `bool operator==(const player & lhs, const player & rhs);`. There is no `==` nor `hash` in the derived types